# Creating Hotfix using TortoiseGIT

Tags: git, tortoisegit

All,

Being a long time user of "**Smart GIT**" I'm finding "**Tortoise GIT**" a little diffcult to work upon (due to the usability constraints).

Basically, I need to create a "**hotfix**" using "**Tortoise GIT**" for which I can't find any relevant menu with the "**Tortoise GIT**" extension.

Based on googling, I got to know that the [Patch Serials](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-patch.html) is one option, but it makes me to do all the changes then to create it, where as if you any other GIT client, you will have option like "**Start Feature**" / "**Start Hotfix**" to have it created them instantly without any hassle.

Can someone shed some light if you know any native options available (in TortoiseGIT) as such?